# wacom tablet intuos DRAW ( CTL-490 ) FAR not work perfectly

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, kde, wacom

tablet name : [Wacom tablet intuos DRAW small](http://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-tablets/intuos-draw) ( CTL - 490 )

current OS   : [KDE Ubuntu 16.04](http://kubuntu.com/getkubuntu) ( 64 bit ) ( **Hungarian** )

current kernel : [4.4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes)

**problem** : the wacom tablet is recognize as Joystick, but work as a touchpad, so i can draw with it, senseless, and buttonless.

the things starts with [Linux MINT 17.3 KDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=216) , but my tablet is not work at all. my linux mint friends tolds me, *this error is because the linux mint uses the very old kernel .* so i am jumps into another [KDE](https://www.kde.org) distro, the kde-ubuntu 16.04 ,because this is using a new kernel. the situation is much better now, **the tablet works as touch pad, and a joystick** ... confusing.

in the settings window, the buttons, and ALL of the sensitive stuff is out of working. **inactive**. the touch pad settings is see nothing , because the "synaptics backend missing. " ... so i am unable to change anything, because ALL the setting button here is gray, **inactive**. sadly the half of the settings screen is english, and half is hungarian

[image]

how interesting is, the synaptics are already installed.
the console told me, the synaptics is already the newest, up to date, version 1.8.2 ( all four zeros. )

[image]

the more interesting stuff is, the tablet is appears on one more tab.
The joystick section !

[image]

of course, the tablet is NOT a joystick, and the buttons surprisely appears VERY good, its means all the buttons work fine, but i am dont know why in this way.

if the question is still not clear for you, i am very sad.

( how i can put back the wacom tablet to work normally ? )

Comment: here is a small photo of the small wacom tablet. 
https://store.wacom.sg/UploadedFiles/Products/Intuos-Draw-Creative-Pen-Tablet-Small---Mint-Blue-h-20150903213618.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

( Tested on [Linux mint 17.3 KDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=216) )

Before build your castle, you will need some [dependencies](http://www.google.com/#q=linux+mint+dependencies) fixed.

++++++++++++++

type this into the Konsole / Terminal :

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential

++++++++++++++

Download the [wacom input 32th version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.32.0.tar.bz2/download) ( TAR.BZ archive ) with any kind of browser.

( https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.32.0.tar.bz2/download )

++++++++++++++

unpack your fresh download with [TAR command](http://www.howtogeek.com/248780/how-to-compress-and-extract-files-using-the-tar-command-on-linux) (go to the location, where you want to INSTALL):

tar xjvf input-wacom-0.32.0.tar.bz2

cd input-wacom-0.32.0

++++++++++++++

and now the last step, the Build and Install

go in the fresh directory ( you remember, the folder's name is "input-wacom-0.32.0" )
and type the following lines ( and BE PATIENCE ) :

./configure

make

sudo make install

+++++++++++

and thats it. REBOOT the system, and after the system boots up, go, and CHECK the WACOM controll panel to be ensure the method is working !
remember, you will suffer a lot, if you enables any kind of 1 line [eyefinity](http://www.google.hu/#q=linux+eyefinity), or another single line multi monitor setting !